# Clarification required in classification of transport modes

Tags: here-api

I am using calculate route in routing api to identify distance and time from source to destination. In developers documents I have seen one of the transport mode as car HOV. What kind of vehicals exactly comes under this category.

Like when I say truck it covers multiple types of vehicals like. Caravan , camper e.t.c. In the same way what comes under car HOV category.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the definition provided for carHOV in Here documentation (developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/transport-modes.html)

carHOV: same as routing for cars, but also allows usage of HOV (high-occupancy vehicle) lanes and roads.

HOV stands for High-occupancy vehicle lane. A high-occupancy vehicle lane (also known as an HOV lane, carpool lane, diamond lane, 2+ lane, and transit lane or T2 or T3 lanes) is a restricted traffic lane reserved for the exclusive use of vehicles with a driver and one or more passengers, including carpools, vanpools, and transit buses. These restrictions may be only imposed during at peak travel times or may apply at all times. The normal minimum occupancy level is 2 or 3 occupants.

YOu can read more about HOV in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-occupancy_vehicle_lane.

Answer (score 0):

In addition there are some rules that mark certain vehicles as equivalent to HOV.

These are defined in map specification and not exposed to routing request / response. Example:
Toll is same as HOV
Motorcycle/Hybrid/Alternative Fuel... is same as HOV

Thus if you are calculating route / travel time you may get status code that route is violating HOV rule (since you didn't specify transport type). In real life it may mean that road is open to carpool or people with "EasyPass" (or equivalent toll system).

An example would be I-66 in VA inside Capital Beltway (USA).